# Could not solve this equation by Solve and also get nearly correct plot by Wolfram|Alpha

Tags: differential-equations, wolfram-alpha-queries

Input:

```
Solve[y'[x] == -(224.8 ((y[x]^2 - y[x]/10^11 - (0.000010385 x^3)/E^(2 x))/x^2)), y[x], x]
```

Output:

```
{y[x] -> 0.0022242 x^2 (2.248*10^-9/x^2 - (1. Sqrt[5.0535*10^-18 +   2.09923        
E^(-2. x) x^3 - 899.2 x^2 Derivative[1][y][x]])/x^2)},
{y[x] -> 0.0022242 x^2 (2.248*10^-9/x^2 + Sqrt[5.0535*10^-18 + 2.09923 E^(-2. x) x^3 - 
899.2 x^2 Derivative[1][y][x]]/x^2)}}
```

[image: Plot of y vs x by Wolfram Alpha]

Using Wolfram Alpha I got nearly a correct plot but the raw wolfram alpha code also seems problematic can any one see this wolfram alpha issue also(Since it is very helpful if i can do some solutions by wolfram alpha also)

Comment: Do you mean `DSolve`?

Answer (score 5):

As Chip suggested, you need DSolve. But if you want to plot it, you also need an initial condition. This is why the Wolfram Alpha plot shows multiple curves... they correspond to different initial conditions. Here's what I got to work:

```
result[x_] = 
  y[x]/.NDSolve[{y'[x]==-(224.8 ((y[x]^2-y[x]/10^11 
    - (0.000010385 x^3)/E^(2 x))/x^2)), y[1] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 8}][[1]]
Plot[result[x],{x,1,8}];
```

[image]